# divide prometheus metric by field value

Tags: prometheus, promql

i have data in prometheus that i would like to get the ratio of; specifically the value i would like to divide by is actually the value contained within a field of the same metric:

```
disk_usage{cluster="home",directory="/m/meme",filesystem="home",hard_quotaGB="30.0",owner="",soft_quotaGB="25.0"} 0.4
```

what i would like is to get the percentage used of the user's quota. or to put it another way, how can i extract the `soft_quotaGB` (25.0) so that i may divide the actual `disk_usage` (0.4) by it?

Answer (score 0):

The soft_quotaGB looks like to me a configuration.

It should be another metric e.g `disk_usage_metadata` that defines these data per user. Then you will be able to divide them joining the metrics by user.

You can use [recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus doesn't provide a function for parsing label values into numbers during queries :(

But such a function is provided by VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. The function is named [label_value](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_value). For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query returns the percentage of `disk_usage` value comparing to the value stored at `soft_quotaGB` label:

```
disk_usage / label_value(disk_usage, "soft_quotaGB")
```